# Disk utility in command line

Tags: command-line, disk-utility

I'm looking for the `CLI` equivalent of "Check disk" and "repair disk" in Disk Utility. I think `fsck` is involved but I don't know with which options, and if it's the only program run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, Disk Utility does use fsck to check the disk in question.
"Verify Disk" uses

```
 /sbin/fsck_hfs -fn -x /dev/diskX
```

while "Repair Disk" runs

```
/sbin/fsck_hfs -fy -x /dev/diskX
```

These are the options used:

-f: 'f'orces a check, even if the disk seems to be clean

-n: 'n'ever attempts to repair any found issues

-y: says 'y'es to any question whether an issues should be repaired (as you might have guessed, -n and -y are exact opposites)

-x: generates output in XML format, which is parsed by Disk Utility

/sbin/fsck (as opposed to /sbin/fsck_hfs) is a wrapper that calls /sbin/fsck_XXX for the type of file system in question.
You'll get more information in the man pages for fsck and fsck_hfs, from which I've borrowed a lot of information for my reply.

Comment: Hum, it seems that the disk utility is doing much more than the single `fsck_hfs -fy`. The former worked, while the latter failed with the message 'Disk reparation faild. Aborting.'.

Answer (score 3):

`/usr/sbin/diskutil` is what you are looking for.

Checkout `man diskutil` and look at the `repairVolume` command.

Comment: The advantage of using `diskutil` over `fsck_hfs`, is that where for example `$ fsck_hfs -fy /dev/disk1s2` might not fix errors found "_** Cannot repair volume when it is mounted with write access.
** The volume Backup could not be repaired._", where `$ diskutil repairVolume /Volumes/Backup` unmounts the Volume and fixes the problems found.